# Rails 5 API - how to create and use a custom serializer with Active Model Serializer for the same model(s)

Tags: active-model-serializers, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How is it possible to create a custom serializer for the same model ?
I already have `ShopSerializer`defined as follows:

```
#serializers/shop_serializer.rb

class ShopSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :category,:name, ...#other attributes

  belongs_to :country
end
```

I would like to define a custom one that includes all the relations:

```
module Api
  class ShopSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :category, ... other attributes

    belongs_to :country
    has_one :address
    has_one :client_relation
    has_many :events
    has_many :services
    has_many :descriptions
  end
end
```

In `controllers/v1/api/shops_controller.rb`:

```
module V1
  module Api
    class ShopsController < ApiController

      def show
        @shop = Shop.some_fancy_method(params[:identifier])
        render jsonapi: @shop, serializer: Api::ShopSerializer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and it fails with:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Shop::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f8e07d5cd88>>",
```

What's wring with that? What am I missing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Shop::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f8e07d5cd88>>"
```

Implies that you're trying to serialize an active relation containing the shop inside of it, rather than just the shop itself.

Should @shop return a singular shop? If so, then:

```
render jsonapi: @shop.first, serializer: Api::ShopSerializer
```

Should work, but obviously it's best to fix the @shop variable in the first place

Comment: But what if I get a relation object?

Comment: Then change how you're calculating the @ shop variable, where you assign it, if there is only ever one record in the relation, you can do @ shop = whatever_you_were_doing.first

Comment: Yep, in the above example I’m getting a AR Relation object containing 1 only shop.

Comment: But the error is still there if I get a collection: `shops = Shop.all`, then: `render jsonapi: @shops, include: ['country', 'services' ], serializer: Api::ShopSerializer`, - this raises `undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for nil:NilClass>`

Comment: Read the error messages you're getting. Undefined method for nil class. That means you're trying to call it on nil now. You assigned a variable called `shops` and are using the variable `@shops`. You're also still using a collection of items instead of one item.

Comment: To spare another few hours of commenting, can you tell me if `render jsonapi: @shop.first, serializer: Api::ShopSerializer` works?

Comment: yes, `render jsonapi: @shop.first, serializer: Api::ShopSerializer` works, thank you. As for `@shops` variable, it was a typo. I do get `@shops = Shop.all`, then `render jsonapi: @shops, serializer: Api::ShopSerializer`. It will raise the same error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Shop::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fa10d980610>)`. If I change `serializer` for `each_serializer:  Api::ShopSerializer` it works. That was the reason.